# Insert rows returns an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to insert rows in an existing table, which is auto generating the id-primary key. Even if I leave the id out, insert returns an error. Looking back the create table is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable](
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[col2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[col3] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[col4] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[col5] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.DataFields] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO
```

How can I insert rows in this table?

Thanks.

Comment: Add the error message.

Comment: Add your current insert statement that is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`NewID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql) function to generate a unique identifier. or if you have a unique ID already generated just insert it's value as string data and the system will implicitly cast it to the uniqueidentifier type (provided is well formed and valid)  or you can explicitly cast/convert if desired. `CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, Value)`

This link shows a working example: of inserting a value into your mytable table... http://rextester.com/QEIY13362

```
CREATE TABLE [mytable](
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[col2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[col3] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[col4] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[col5] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.DataFields] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
);

insert into mytable (ID, col2,col3,col4,col5) values (newID(), 'Test','Test2','Test3','Test4');

insert into mytable (ID, col2,col3,col4,col5) values ('a3ce8a7d-9b7e-428a-ab7d-948f81e3926a', 'Test','Test2','Test3','Test4');

Select * from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends which technology do you use. 
If oracle, you can use a sequence for the unique identifier. 
sometimes it works also using nothing like this :

```
insert into mytable (col2,col3,col4,col5) 
   values ('Test','Test2','Test3','Test4');
```

or you can use newId() as said in one of comments.

if SQL server then you can use auto increment like this :

```
 Id  INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(10000000, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
```

and then when you insert u do as I said without mentioning the ID.

Comment: FYI: tag shows it's sql-server (though we don't know the version)